# How can I run/call a Makefile from golang code?

Tags: go, makefile, protocol-buffers, proto

I need to compile proto files and generate pb files dynamically. I have my protoc commands in a Makefile. I am planning to trigger this from golang init() function.

How can I call this Makefile from my golang code? Tried finding solution, but all of them suggest how I can achieve this the other way round.

Thanks.

Comment: put your generated files as a dependency of your go command. add command to generate your files and this will do the trick

Comment: Use https://godoc.org/os/exec to execute commands like make.  Compiling proto files is one of the use cases for the `go generate` command . See  https://blog.golang.org/generate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a continuation to what Muffin Top mentioned, I achieved this using the below code:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func init() {
    e := exec.Command("make", "all")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    e.Stdout = &out
    err := e.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Output: %q\n", out.String())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the go:generate syntax:

```
package main

//go:generate protoc bla bla bla
```

When you run your "go build" command, it will then run everything in your code prefixed with //go:generate

https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/generate/

Comment: My requirement is slightly different. This approach wont work for me

Comment: `go build` does not look at go:generate instructions. `go generate` does. Neither happens at runtime, which is the goal here.